# implementation of spring batch finish correctly but not inserting all rows in database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, oracle11g, spring-batch

We are using Spring Batch to load data from a flat file, in the inserting phase into the database using the saveAll (or save) method from jpa, we cannot insert all the rows even though the Job ends correctly.
We validate that the writer method and the saveall response says that it all the data was inserted, but in the database we have a trigger before inserting and says was executed approximately 980 times out of 1000 records.

when the job is executed, it does not activate the afterChunkError and onWriteError methods

It is also validated that the imported file has the correct data and the database table has no key constraint.

configuration and versions:
the job steps are executed in a single thread
jpa version 2.7.12
version Spring Batch 4.3.8
DB Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2

I tried to configure the steps by threads but no improvement was achieved and it is necessary for the process to insert all the records